# Send write request to BLE device via GATT (UWP)

Tags: c#, android, bluetooth, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a BLE device (a fitness tracker), which e.x. shows a message when I send a specific write request to it.

In Android it all works great. The device shows instantly, that it received a message:

```
BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = ... //connecting to BLE device with specific UUID
byte[] data = new byte[] {(byte)0x01, 0x01};
characteristic.setValue(data);
mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
```

But in my UWP app, the BLE device doesn't show any reaction:

```
var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(GattDeviceService.GetDeviceSelectorFromUuid(new Guid("00001811-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")), null);
GattDeviceService service = await GattDeviceService.FromIdAsync(devices[0].Id);
var gattCharacteristic = service.GetCharacteristics(new Guid("00002a46-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")).First();

//Writing request
var writer = new DataWriter();
writer.WriteBytes(new byte[] { 0x01, 0x01 });
await gattCharacteristic.WriteValueAsync(writer.DetachBuffer());
```

Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: What is the result value from WriteValueAsync?

Comment: The result value is GattCommunicationStatus.Success

Comment: I ran into the same issue. Moreover, my application works well on notebook, but does not work on windows phone. It's seems like the issue in Windows or Phone. Have you tried to run this code on different devices?

Comment: @Knyaz Thanks for your response, I ran this code also on my Notebook and other phones, but it won't work, too

Comment: To localize the issue, I suggest to try send data using other reliable application (I used Bluetooth LE Lab) on the same phone/notebook. If it works, there is a problem in your code. BTW, I use 'var request = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(new byte[] { 0xa0, 0x1f });' to create data buffer - it works.

Answer (score 2):

It can be that you are not connected or you are using the wrong gattCharacteristic service.

Anyway this is how i successfully write to my device:

```
private async Task SendValues(byte[] toSend)
{      
  IBuffer writer = toSend.AsBuffer();
  try
  {
     // BT_Code: Writes the value from the buffer to the characteristic.         
     var result = await gattCharacteristic.WriteValueAsync(writer);
     if (result == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
     {
        //Use for debug or notyfy
        var dialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Succes");
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
     }
     else
     {
        var dialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Failed");
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
     }
  }
  catch (Exception ex) when ((uint)ex.HResult == 0x80650003 || (uint)ex.HResult == 0x80070005)
  {
     // E_BLUETOOTH_ATT_WRITE_NOT_PERMITTED or E_ACCESSDENIED
     // This usually happens when a device reports that it
     //support writing, but it actually doesn't.
     var dialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(ex.Message);
     await dialog.ShowAsync();
  }
}
```

Comment: I used the same code as you did, but the result is the same. The device is connected (I checked it with `service.Device.ConnectionStatus`) and I used exactly the UUID's from my android app. I can't guess why it won't work.